# If $K = F(\alpha)$ is a non separable and finite extension, then $T^K_F = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, trace, separable-extension

I am trying to prove that if $K = F(\alpha)$ is a non separable and finite extension then $T^K_F = 0$. Now, I looked at a solution and it goes as follows: Suppose the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $f=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$, then $\{1, \alpha, ... \alpha^{n-1}\}$ is a basis for $K$. Now, consider the linear transformation $x \to \alpha \cdot x$. It is easy to check that the trace of the matrix which represents this linear transformation with respect to the above basis is exactly $-a_{n-1}$. But since the extension is not seperable, $f$ must be a polynomial in $x^p$ (where $p=char(F)$) and therefore $a_{n-1}=0$. Now, I understand that it proves that $T^{K}_F (\alpha) = 0$, but why does it prove that $T^K_F =0$? Say, I don't understand why for example $T^K_F(\alpha^2)=0$. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have $T^K_F=T^M_F\circ T^K_M$ for any intermediate field $M$, it follows that
$$
T^K_F(\alpha^2)=T^{F(\alpha^2)}_F\circ T^K_{F(\alpha^2)}(\alpha^2)=[K:F(\alpha^2)]T^{F(\alpha^2)}_F(\alpha^2)=0.
$$
In the same way, $T_F^K(\alpha^i)=0$ for all $i$. Then by the $F$-linearity of the trace you get $T_F^K=0$.

Comment: Why are the middle and last equality true? Actually I am starting to think that the problem is false. If we take a root $\alpha$ of the polynomial $f=x^4+x^2+1$ over the algebraic closure of $F_2$, then for $K=F_2(\alpha)$ we have that $K/F_2$ is not seperable, but since $f$ is irreducible it is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, so the basis for $K$ is $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3$, but the matrix representing the linear transformation $x \to \alpha^2 \cdot x$ with respect to that basis has trace $-2$ and not $0$. Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: @Omer The middle equality is because of the fact: If $K/F$ is a finite extension and $\alpha\in F$, then $T_F^K(\alpha)=[K:F]\alpha$. The last equality can be justified like this: for any $i$, since $K/F$ is inseparable, then either $K/F(\alpha^i)$ or $F(\alpha^i)/F$ is inseparable. If $K/F(\alpha^i)$ is, then $p\mid[K:F(\alpha^i)]$. If $F(\alpha^i)/F$ is, then $T_F^{F(\alpha^i)}(\alpha^i)=0$. Hence $[K:F(\alpha^i)]T_F^{F(\alpha^i)}(\alpha^i)=0$. To your example, I think it is not a counterexample, since finite fields are perfect, and hence $K/F_2$ is a separable extension.

Comment: @Omer To say a little more, if you know the characterisation (for any $\beta\in K$) $$T_F^K(\beta)=[K:F]_i\sum_{\sigma}\sigma(\beta)$$ where $\sigma$ goes over all $F$-embedding of $K$ into the algebraic closure $\overline F$ and $[K:F]_i$ is the inseparable degree, then $T_F^K=0$ is immediate.